# UI is freeze while adding items to list control

Tags: c++, mfc, listcontrol

My app is freeze while I click the button to add items to list control. I'm doing it simple:

```
for (unsigned i = 1; i < 15000;++i)
{
  listcontrol1.InsertItem(i, L"item list");
}
```

I also tried using a background thread but the same results.
Any idea how to do this correctly without blocking the user interface ?

Answer (score 1):

pouring 15k messages into the message pump is going to be slow.

Better use a [virtual list control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye4z8x58.aspx) with proper caching. See the [VListVW Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940571(v=vs.85).aspx) in %Windows SDK Dir%\Samples\winui\controls\common\vlistvw for working code.

Comment: It would be nice to add a code example or some more details, as it stands this answer is a link only answer and if the link stops working then it won't be helpful to future users.

Comment: well I guess given this is an FAQ in Win32 programming I should not assume the asker has google skills... my bad.

Answer (score 1):

As Sheng Jiang stated the virtual list is the best solution for such a great list. But you can improve the performance avoiding control paintings during insertion:

```
listcontrol1.SetRedraw(FALSE);
for (unsigned i = 1; i < 15000; ++i)
{
    listcontrol1.InsertItem(i, L"item list");
}
listcontrol1.SetRedraw(TRUE);
```